# Adding texts in a ms word file through PHP

Tags: php

I have a ms word file with few texts, is there any way to add few texts in it using php code.

for instance, I have a word file and it has text like 'My name is.....', i would like to add one name in the dotted place using php code.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at libraries like [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use Libraries like [PHPWORD](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).It provides a set of classes to write to and read from different document file formats.
You can also use  `phpLiveDocx` which is a Zend Framework component and can read and write DOC and DOCX files in PHP on Linux, Windows and Mac.
A sample code to do this with [PHP COM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php)

```
<?php 
// Create COM instance to word 

       function clsMSWord($Visible = false) 
   { 
       $this->handle = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instanciate Word"); 
       $this->handle->Visible = $Visible; 
   } 

function WriteHyperlink($Bookmark,$Path,$Text) 
   { 
           $objBookmark = $this->handle->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks($Bookmark); 
           $range = $objBookmark->Range; 
           $objHyperlink = $this->handle->ActiveDocument->Hyperlinks; 
           $objHyperlink->add($range,$Path,"","",$Text); 

   }
```

Comment: this would be a comment, which is already posted by MarkBaker on the question long before your answer. Please delete this and upvote the comment saying the same thing as your answer...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier see i have reeditted my answer..i think now you should remove the downvote

Comment: Add some code sample with how to do it and I'll surely upvote it :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier now check i have given the code to do it with com CLASS..:)